# Move a current debian installation to a new harddrive without re-installing

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian

Forgive me if this has been answered but after a search at least I couldn't find one that handles my case. Feel free to link if it has been answered.

I currently have a 750GB drive with the following layout:

```
/dev/sda1 - ntfs - 100MiB (suppose that was generated by windows)
/dev/sda2 - ntfs - 50GiB - boot (Win7 partition)
/dev/sda3 - ext4 - 48GiB - /home
/dev/sda4 - extended - 600GiB
  /dev/sda5 - ext4 - 48GiB - /
  /dev/sda6 - ext4 - 10GiB - /tmp
  /dev/sda7 - ext3 - 500GiB - /backup
  /dev/sda9 - ntfs - 34GiB - win7 software
  /dev/sda8 - linux-swap - 10GiB
unallocated - 2.5MiB
```

I purchased a new 120GB SSD and want to move my debian installation to the new drive completely to gain as much speed as possible out of it. With that it should also boot from the new device and not from that windows partition anymore.
So sda3, sda5, sda6 and sda8 should move to the new drive. The rest of the unused space on that new drive should merge with sda3 (/home).
On the old drive sda1, sda2 should stay. sda3 should be merged with sda2. And all the rest of the space should be merged with sda7.

I think I know how to delete and move/merge space. I will use gparted for this.
Except for sda7 maybe. It is now on an extended partition. Can I safely turn this into a normal partition as there will only be 3 after all the moving? Or is that even needed?

What I do not know is the best way to move the debian partitions to the new drive without the need of re-installing either debian or windows. Is it possible?
There is no hardware change except the new drive that is being installed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do that by creating the corresponding partitions in the new drive and then cloning with http://clonezilla.org/

You could even create a bigger partition for /home